# tabs disappear after I load a built in application

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am really lost here.

I have an application which uses  3 XML files which each xml file is for each tabs ( i have 3 tabs with my app), which works fine. Under one of the tab there is a button, which when I click on it , it meant to pick up the name and number from the contact application and print it in that tab's screen, which is done by connecting to database and picking up names and number after being selected from the contact app. they all work fine.

But always after the process and picking up data and setting the textview values under the tb3, the main 3 tabs are disapeared and also all the 3 diffrent XML fileas are combined together Does anyone knows why?

Does anyone knows what to do ?any tutorial ?

someone suggested *Fragmentmanager* but I have no idea how to use that?

Pleas, please someone help me with this.

Here is the code for main activity which shows the tabs :

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    Button addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);


    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("tab1",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab1)).setContent(R.id.tab1Layout));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("tab2",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab2)).setContent(R.id.tab2Layout));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("tab3",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab3)).setContent(R.id.tab3));

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

    addbutton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 

        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,ContactsDemo.class); 

        MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent,1); 

        } 

        }); 

}
```

}

This suppose to open myActivity and then goes back to the MainAcitiviy. But after it loads the other activity, all three tabs disappears and all the three xml files combines.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: hi Hamza I have added the codes:)

Answer (score 0):

Given your information I can only assume that `addButton` is a `Button` on one of your Tabs and that you want to return to the originating tab or one of the other two. I've built a similar app and I think you have to place the `startActivityForResult()`-call in one of the tab-activities, since you mentioned tb3 this would be a good start. When I do a `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`-call and this new activity is closed or the user hits the back-button I'm back on my tab with the tabs-ribbon visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have figured out the problem last month actually. I have added a Finish(); method at the end of the oncreate() method of ContactsDemo.class and that sort out the problem. However many thanks for your answer :)